# How to stop form from sending empty or wrong data?

Tags: php, forms

I have just now completed building this form and it is running quite well, thanks to the user community of stackoverflow; but I have now noticed an issue with my form while testing it in different scenarios.

The major problem is that it is sending information regardless of any information being present and regardless of whether the user has entered correct data. The error is showing up on the page, but the data is being sent, even when error is being displayed on the page.

I want to find out how to stop the form from sending an E-mail, when the fields are empty or have wrong content entered into them?

Here is the PHP code, I am using:

```
<?php

function test_input($data){

    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;
}

function clean_string($string) {

    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

}


// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $emailErr = $overviewErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $overview = "";

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "myself@mydomain.com";
$email_subject = "Contact us - My company's name";
{

if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
{$first_nameErr = "(First Name is required)";}

else
{$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
      {
      $first_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
      }
    }

if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
{$last_nameErr = "(Last Name is required)";}

else
    {$last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name))
      {
      $last_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
      }
    }

if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {$emailErr = "(Email ID is required)";}

else
    {$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

// check if e-mail address syntax is valid
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
      {
      $emailErr = "(Invalid email format)"; 
      }
    }

if (empty($_POST["overview"]))
    {$overviewErr = "(Overview is required)";}

else
    {$overview = test_input($_POST["overview"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$overview))
      {
      $overview = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
      }
    }

}

//Email & SEND INFO
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string(implode(', ', $service))."\n";

    $email_message .= "Overview: ".clean_string($overview)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- Success HTML -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: It's hard to follow those conditional blocks, the spacing/nesting is really awkward.  But it looks like the code which sends the mail isn't inside any condition, so it's going to run no matter what.  If you only want it to run when certain conditions are met, wrap it in an `if` which checks those conditions.

Comment: yeah, the conditional blocks look really screwy, after the line $email_subject = "Contact us - My company's name"; you have an opening brace { which i think should be a closing one ie. } and you don't have a closing brace here: {$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);

Comment: Your indentation is... inventive.

Comment: @jx12345 I am new to PHP coding, so can you tell me if I should place a closing brace after every one of the test_input()s?

Comment: the opening and closing braces signify code blocks so on your if and else statements you need to use the correctly. eg. if (something) { //do this //do that //etc } else { //do this //do that //etc }

Comment: i'll write it out in an answer so you can see more clearly

Comment: @jx12345 Please do write it as an answer and could you tell me a solution for mt problem, regarding the mail being sent even when the fields are empty or filled with wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are wanting to stop the form from sending any data if there is nothing to send in the forms, right? If so then you need to do that via javascript. The easiest way would be with jquery. I suggest [This tutorial](http://www.raymondselda.com/php-contact-form-with-jquery-validation/). That will help you get off the ground

Answer (score 0):

I think your code blocks might be incorrect try this:

```
<?php

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

// define variables and set to empty values
$first_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $emailErr = $overviewErr = "";
$first_name = $last_name = $email = $overview = "";

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "myself@mydomain.com";
    $email_subject = "Contact us - My company's name";
}

if (empty($_POST["first_name"])) {
    $first_nameErr = "(First Name is required)";
} else {
    $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
}

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name)) {
      $first_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
}

if (empty($_POST["last_name"])) {
   $last_nameErr = "(Last Name is required)";
} else {
   $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
}

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name)) {
    $last_name = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "(Email ID is required)";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
}

// check if e-mail address syntax is valid
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
    $emailErr = "(Invalid email format)"; 
}

if (empty($_POST["overview"])) {
    $overviewErr = "(Overview is required)";
} else {
    $overview = test_input($_POST["overview"]);
}

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$overview)) {
  $overview = "(Only letters and white space allowed)"; 
}


//Email & SEND INFO
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Services: ".clean_string(implode(', ', $service))."\n";
$email_message .= "Overview: ".clean_string($overview)."\n";


// create email headers 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


if ($first_nameErr || $last_nameErr || $emailErr || $overviewErr) {
    echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.";
} else {
    echo "There are some errors in your form: " . $first_nameErr . ', ' . $last_nameErr . ', ' . $emailErr . ', ' . $overviewErr;
}
```

Not sure if that'll fix everything but it should be easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I used the code you gave me. Now, it has stopped sending an email alltogether, but still is showing success HTML.

Comment: Sorry Dude, but now, it has stopped displaying the whole page alltogether. If I refresh the page, it is just showing up as a blank page. Help me..